# Not able to get SOAP response after calling external webservice from java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, saaj

I have a requrement of calling an external webservice from java where I will where I will create the SOAP request and pass to the webservice and will get the SOAP response back ... I went through the following url :- http://www.concretepage.com/webservices/java-saaj-web-service-example    to acheive it... My **SOAP request** is as follow :-

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <v1:retrieveDataRequest>
         <v1:Id>22</v1:Id>
      </v1:retrieveDataRequest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and my **SOAP response** is :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <retrieveDataResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
         <Response>The Data retrieved from the Database</Response>
         <Id>21</Id>
         <Name>fdfdf</Name>
         <Age>44</Age>
         <Designation>dgdgdfg</Designation>
      </retrieveDataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and my **Java code** is :-

```
import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Main2
{
        /**
         * Method used to create the SOAP Request
         */
        private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception
        {
                MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
                SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

                /*
                Construct SOAP Request Message:
                <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <v1:retrieveDataRequest>
         <v1:Id>21</v1:Id>
      </v1:retrieveDataRequest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
                 */

                // SOAP Envelope
                SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
                envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("v1", "http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1");

                // SOAP Body
                SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
                SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("retrieveDataRequest", "v1");
                SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Id", "v1");
                soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("21");

                MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
                headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1"  + "http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1/retrieveDataOperation");

                soapMessage.saveChanges();

                // Check the input
                System.out.println("Request SOAP Message = ");
                soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
                System.out.println();
                return soapMessage;
        }

        /**
         * Method used to print the SOAP Response
         */
        private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception
        {
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
                System.out.println("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
        }

        /**
         * Starting point for the SAAJ - SOAP Client Testing
         */
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                try
                {
                         // Create SOAP Connection
                        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
                        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

                        //Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
                        String url = "http://localhost:8082/mainData?wsdl";
                        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

                        // Process the SOAP Response
                        printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

                        soapConnection.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Now my issue is I am getting the **SOAP request** printed in console but I and not getting the **SOAP response** back from the service ... Please help ... How to get the SOAP response printed in console ... I am not able to get response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just try this to capture the response?

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
msg.writeTo(out);
String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
```